# How to use private IP address in router machine

Tags: routing, masquerade

I would like to use **192.168.11.1**, but use global IP address againt my will.

I would not like to use global IP address in router when Im usging web browser and client applications.

How do I do ?

Now: my web browser(my global IP address) -> the internet

I'd like to:my web browser(private IP address(192.168.11.1)) -> my global IP address -> the internet

Thank you for reading my question.

My machine.
Debian9(kvm and vps)

virtual nic ens3 -> global IP address

virtual nic ens4 -> 192.168.11.1/24

`# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.11.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 ens4
default         {global ip gateway}    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens3
localnet        0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 ens3
192.168.11.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens4`

`# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.11.0/24 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: The topic has been deemed unclear, i do not think it is unclear and i am very against this decision. It's a simple question of NAT / PAT, getting ens4 clients with private addresses out ens3 on his / her public address.

Comment: @CristianMatthiasAmbæk  IMO What makes it unclear is the OP didn't really say what he is trying to achieve. If we wanted to use 192.168.11.1/24 for internal purposes that would be an easy fix however it looks like he wants to use 192.168.11.1/24 as an external gateway which is not possible. what he could do is something like here https://serverfault.com/questions/430459/how-to-set-a-static-route-for-an-external-ip-address but we still don't know what he is tying to accomplish.